# Manipulating tensors matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to do operations on a 3-d sparse matrix (If I don't precise that's sparse matrix, I have a "out-of-memory" error). However, using matlab's default toolbox, I can't create a sparse tensor. So I've installed some toolbox (tensor-toolbox 2.5 : http://www.sandia.gov/~tgkolda/TensorToolbox/index-2.5.html) and I'm trying the function SPTENSOR. But, my progam doesn't work anymore (some operations are not supported). ==> ??? Error using ==> sptensor.subsasgn at 200 Invalid RHS

Have you got any idea to solve my problem (by using this toolbox, or not)?

Comment: Can you give the codes here?